# Connect to host machine from WSL2

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tunneling, socat

**Problem**

Can't connect to Windows X Server (VcXsrv) from WSL2 due firewall rules (sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesnt; it's very strange). Changing the firewall rules is not possible.

But any connection from Windows to WSL2 just works.

**Idea**

Is it possible to run a client/server pair as an intermediary service, to mirror any service on the WSL and make it accessible from the WSL?

```
------------Windows Host------------
| [Windows X Server] <--- [Client] |
-----------------------------↑------
                             |
----------------WSL----------v---------
| [XGui Client] ---> [Mirror service] |
---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But any connection from Windows to WSL2 just works

As background, it's important to understand that the WSL2 network is NAT'd behind a virtual, Hyper-V switch.  It really is a *separate* layer 2 network from the Windows host.

Communication *from* Windows *to* WSL2 is considered *outbound* traffic from Windows, and inbound to WSL2, so no firewall rules are needed.  By default, Windows allows most outbound traffic, and your Linux distribution running under WSL2 accepts most inbound traffic.

We can use that to our advantage in this case ...

> Is it possible to run a client/server pair as an intermediary service, to mirror any service on the WSL and make it accessible from the WSL?

You have this tagged [socat](/questions/tagged/socat) and that's a reasonable idea.  I've used `socat` before in a similar way successfully, but (a) it's been a while, (b) I'd need to reproduce the recipe I used and tweak it to the X server, and (c) `socat`'s options are kind of a pain to work through.  It's powerful, but not necessarily easy to use.

So let me propose a built-in, much easier alternative -- `ssh` from Windows to WSL2 with X forwarding.  It's really designed to do just this type of traversal.

- Enable the OpenSSH *client* for Windows (see [doc] (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui#install-openssh-for-windows).  No need for the server in this case, since you'd have to open a firewall rule for that (which you've said you can't).  It's already *installed* with Windows, you just need to enable the feature.
- Enable the SSH server in your Linux distribution under WSL2.  You don't mention which distribution you are running, but under Ubuntu (the default distribution), you need to (if I recall correctly):

  - Edit the sshd config:  `sudo -e /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and choose a different port -- Let's say 2222.
  - Optionally enable `PasswordAuthentication` if you won't be using a key.
  - Ensure that `X11Forwarding=yes`, which it already should in Ubuntu.
  - Save and exit.
  - `sudo service ssh start`
  - If you get a message about host keys missing, try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` and then restart the service.
- From Windows, start `XLaunch` (VcXsrv) with the default options + *"Disable access control"*.
- From PowerShell:

  ```
  $env:DISPLAY="localhost:0"
  ssh -Y -p 2222 wslusername@localhost
  ```

  Note: See [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/1610187/1210833) for why the `localhost` is critical in this case.
- You should be logged into the WSL2 instance, with X forwarding in place.  `xterm`, etc. should launch into VcXsrv.

Comment: Awsome! This works, thank you. I have some questions though: Is my assumption correct, that the ssh client, will automatically set an DISPLAY environment variable on the ssh host (wsl)? How is the connection working exactly? Does that correspond to my description in the question post? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Arber Glad it helped!  I originally was going down a different path that was more similar to your description (forwarding port 6000), but X is a tricky beast.  The `ssh -X` (or `-Y`) mechanism's are "smart" about X forwarding.  For other types of services, I still use `ssh`, but with its "port forwarding" (rather than X-forwarding) arguments.  See [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413406/1165986) for an example (although in the *opposite* direction).  The "port forwarding" is more like your original description than this one.

Comment: And yes, `ssh -Y` automatically sets the `DISPLAY` variable inside the connection to WSL.  You'll see that it has changed to something like `localhost:10.0` to map it to the SSH server's "proxy".